# How to convert Youtube URL to RTSP URL?

Tags: android, youtube, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

In my project I want to dowload a Youtube URL and play it in media player but as far I have searched I got an idea that Youtube URLs can be played only if they are converted into a RTSP file. I don't have any idea of how to do that. It would be very helpful if you send me a sample project.

```
public class Video_Media_PlayerActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoViewDemo";

    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private EditText mPath;
    private ImageButton mPlay;
    private ImageButton mPause;
    private ImageButton mReset;
    private ImageButton mStop;
    private String current;
    String tempPath;
    private VideoMediaViewApplication appObj;
    private int mVideoQuality = 80;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
        mPath.setText("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");

        mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playVideo();

            }
        });
        mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });
        mReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.seekTo(0);
                }
            }
        });
        mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    current = null;
                    mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                }
            }
        });
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                playVideo();


            }

        });
    }

    private void playVideo() {
        try {
            final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
            Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
            if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(Video_Media_PlayerActivity.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
                if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    return;

                }
                current = path;
                mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
        if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
            return path;
        } else {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
            cn.connect();
            InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
            if (stream == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
            //prepareDirectory();
            //File file1 = new File(path);
            File file1 = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
            file1.deleteOnExit();
            tempPath = file1.getAbsolutePath();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file1);
            byte buf[] = new byte[128];
            do {
                int numread = stream.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
                out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            } while (true);
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            return tempPath;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i can give you a name: JDownloader is an opensource project about a download manager, is also written in Java, and it works perfectly when downloading video from Youtube, maybe you can download the source and search for the right module or ask in their forum. jdownloader.org

Answer (score 1):

Use http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/T9W4jgq9RfQ api

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String video_id;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        try {    
        String link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9W4jgq9RfQ&feature=related";
            String pattern = "(?:videos\\/|v=)([\\w-]+)";

            Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(link);

            if(matcher.find()){
                System.out.println(matcher.group().substring(2));
video_id=matcher.group().substring(2);
            }

             DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();


             Document doc1=db.parse("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/"+video_id);

          Element rsp = (Element)doc1.getElementsByTagName("media:content").item(1);

          String anotherurl=rsp.getAttribute("url");
          System.out.println("my "+anotherurl);
         // Element rsp = (Element)doc1.getElementsByTagName("media:content").item(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }
    }
```